# Wordpress Category Tracking Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog with Google Analytics enabled globally. I want to know how many page views or users I'm getting for specific categories. Is there a way to filter analytics by urls like mysite.com/sport/ or mysite.com/entertainment/ ? 
The Google Analytics dashboard looks very intimidating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply an Advanced (inline) Filter to your All Pages report like this:

[image]

Alternatively, you could use "Begins With" to match everything under the "sport" folder (same thing applies to other folders you are interested in, including "entertainment".

This can also be done in Custom Reports or with advanced segments, too.